# Stretch UIView in a ContentView of a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have the following problem:

I have a Scrollview with Autolayout top,left,bottom,right is set on 0, in this ScrollView is a ContentView also set everything on 0. The ContentView contains a ImageView a Segmented Control and a UIView which is connected to 2 different UIViewController.

The UIView is set top 0 to the Segmented Control and to bottom 0 to the contentView.

My Problem is that the UIView in the ContentView is not streets to the bottom of the ContentView. How can i solved this Problem?

Picture 1:
[Storyboard UIViewController with ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYnNa.png)

Picture 2: 
[View on an iPhone 6 Plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKPP9.png)

Here there are the size inspector constraints pictures:

- [ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcBHO.png)
- [MainView of Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sRQ2.png)
- [ContentView in ScrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/madfZ.png)
- [UIView in ContentView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgtdR.png)

Comment: Can you show the size inspector constraints about your elements? Just make some pictures..

Comment: [MainView of Controller](http://i.imgur.com/x9R0p6Q.png?1), [ScrollView](http://i.imgur.com/IyMHVNL.png?1)

Comment: [ContentView in ScrollView](http://i.imgur.com/zOz48J6.png?1), [UIView in ContentView](http://i.imgur.com/z6eAiOV.png?1)

Comment: The Problem is that the ContentView has not the correct height. But with the Constaint 0 it should have the same height as the ScrollView or i am incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is in scroll view bottom content inset. By default scroll view have `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property enabled, and if you insert scroll view as nearest view to tab bar (as I can see at screenshot), bottom inset will set as nonzero (this used for show content under transparent tab bar while scrolling). But for use this behavior properly, you should connect scroll view bottom to `view` (root view) bottom, not to `bottomLayoutGuide`. Second option - disable `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property and handle `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` properties of scroll view manually (set them to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` if you don't want change your constraints).